# Backbone.js model urlRoot webapp folder name getting appended twice

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

i'm working on a web app with backbone.js +codeigniter called shelfari
the directory structure is as follows

[Dir structure http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2506/c180.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2506/c180.png)

I have placed "shelfari" folder in htdocs  and accessing the website site as

```
http://localhost/shelfari/
```

When calling the model.save method i want to send a post request to

```
POST http://localhost/shelfari/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp
```

so i define my model  this way

```
var BookItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot:'codeigniter/index.php/bookapp/',
```

but it sending a post request

```
POST http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp/  404 not found
```

so then i redefined url

```
var BookItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot:'shelfari/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp/',
```

then it sends a post request too

```
POST http://localhost/shelfari/shelfari/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp/  bad error
```

what shoud i do to send the request as

```
POST http://localhost/shelfari/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp
```

please help me find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a "/" in front of the URL: "/shelfari/codeigniter/index.php/bookapp/"

Two additional suggestions:

1) Have you considering using an .htaccess file in your root to insert index.php into your request URLs? I believe it is a Codeigniter best practice and it allows you to use much cleaner URLs without the "index.php" segment of the URL. See below for an example.

2) Are you using an index function the "bookapp" controller? If not, it appears that you may be missing a segment in your URL. Your URL should follow this pattern:
`http://www.domainname.com/index.php/controllername/functionname`,
where `controllername` is the name of the controller that contains the function you are calling and `functionname` is the name of the function in the controller.
If you format an .htaccess file and place it in your root, you can remove the index.php from the URL for a much cleaner `http://www.domainname.com/controllername/functionname`

Comment: hey thnkx semanticMike putting / in front of the url worked :D

Answer (score 0):

```
urlRoot="codegigniter/"
```

You were using a prefix slash, which assumes you're poiting to the localhost document root. When you do not use that slash, the path will be placed after your current url.

```
Host: localhost/shelfari
urlRoot = "/codigniter"
```

Makes the final url `localhost/codeigniter` because you use that slash

```
Host: localhost/shelfari
urlRoot = "codigniter" (note the missing slash)
```

Makes the final url `localhost/shelfari/codeigniter` because the urlRoot will be appended to shelfari.

Best practice is to use absolute paths, so with slash. So the best option for your urlRoot is `/shelfari/codeigniter/......`

I suggest you to use the windows host file so you get a clean url and these problems do not exist anymore.

And please fix your post format, it's hard to read

Comment: hey LHolleman i have edited my question so can u please to revoke tht  -1 to my answer and why just windows!!. i need a platform independent answer and i suppose i making some foolish mistake and the solution doesnt require me to edit windows host file for tht matter

Comment: All commonly-used operating systems have a `hosts` file which uses the same syntax regardless of OS. On Unix-family systems (Linux, OSX, etc.) it's /etc/hosts.

Comment: the issue is with backbone.js which is a client side javascript lib
and do u know backbone.js

Comment: I just assumed you were using windows, every OS has a hosts file. With this file you can fake a domain name for just your computer. For example, shelfari.dev. When you use this, your development environment will look closer to your final webserver which will probably be shelfari.com (or something). So you do not need to change the paths when implementing the website.